# Confused creating an xlsx file in R

Tags: r, openxlsx

I'm trying to read a txt file and create an xlsx out of it. and here is my code.

```
setwd("~/Downloads/Test")
FILES <- list.files( pattern = ".txt")
library(openxlsx)
for (i in 1:length(FILES)) {
  FILE=read.delim(FILES[i],header=F,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sep = "\t",, quote = "")
  colnames(FILE) <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
  write.csv(FILE,file="Dummy.xls")
}
```

when I run this piece of code, I'm able to create an Excel file with `xls` extension, but when I try to do the same with `xlsx`, by changing `file="Dummy.xlsx"`, the file is getting created, but when I open it, I'm getting the below error.

[image: Error image]

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using the openxlsx package you need to use `write.xlsx` instead of `write.csv`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @phiver, I tried that even, I get the error as `“Dummy.xlsx” can’t be imported.`, Instead of `“Dummy.xlsx” can’t be opened right now.`

Comment: You do know that you are continuously overwriting your dummy file? I checked on my machine with some txt files I have lying around and it just does what should. Are you trying to open the xlsx file while your process is still running?

Comment: @phiver, I'm sorry to say that I'm not able to understand what is happening, here is what I'm trying to do is, there is only 1 file in a folder (later I'll add more, that's the reason for using this `loop`), and finds the text file, create a new xlsx file named `Dummy.xlsx`, with the column names as given in the question, and the data comes in from txt file(which is tab separated). I'm able to create `csv`, `.xls` files, but the problem comes up only when I create `.xlsx` using this method :(

Comment: Are you using this as your last line `write.xlsx(FILE, file = "Dummy.xlsx")`?

Comment: @phiver yes. changed my code and using the line that you've mentioned above.